# mysql get number between two field containig 20digit long decimal number

Tags: mysql, select, comparison

I have table 'serial' containing two field with start_serial_no and end_serial_no
which have serials about 20 digit longs(may vary).

I have 3 entries in table as

[image]

User will enter serial number, I have to find in which start and end pair it belongs.
I am using following but it returns two values as output(1st and third) for
'899190150504778850' and third for '899190150504778950'.
Instead it should return only third for both.

```
SELECT *
FROM `serial`
WHERE '899190150504778850'
BETWEEN `start_serial_no`
AND `end_serial_no`
```

Comment: seems like you are doing it right

Comment: i think so, also did not find any solution elsewhere, still searching

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: As suggested in the comment, it seems `longint` can only store numbers up to [a range of 0 to 18446744073709551615 for unsigned numbers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) and `varchar` can be used to achieve the same for number higher than this.

--

Your code is completely correct. It outputs exactly what you want - in this case, it only return the third set of data.

I tried it by creating the exact columns and inserting the exact data into a table. Running your query gave me the desired result.

[image: See screenshots of table structure, data and query result.]

Try again with the same query. If you encounter any problem, please follow up.

Comment: `bigint` does not store 20 digit long no, thanks for reply , solved by making it varchar instead of decmal

Comment: Strange. It seems you are right about the 20-digit number. It can only store up to [a range of 0 to 18446744073709551615 for unsigned numbers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html). But it worked for me (as shown above).

If you figured it out using `varchar`, then good for you! I'll update my answer accordingly.